# Updating rows with column from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table looking like this:

```
id_product  | id_code | content
----------- | ------- | -------------------
1           | 1       | a
1           | 2       | ''
1           | 3       | ''
2           | 1       | b
2           | 2       | ''
2           | 3       | ''
3           | 1       | c
3           | 2       | ''
3           | 3       | ''
```

The results I would like to achieve are something like this:

```
id_product  | id_code | content
----------- | ------- | -------------------
1           | 1       | a
1           | 2       | a
1           | 3       | a
2           | 1       | b
2           | 2       | b
2           | 3       | b
3           | 1       | c
3           | 2       | c
3           | 3       | c
```

In short, I'd like the query to copy the content column down, where id_code is 1, for each id_product.

AFAIK it requires an update query combined with a join, but I'm unsure how to string it together. The hardest part seems to be making it dynamic so that it can perform the query on all of the id_products.

Let me know if anymore info is required.

Here is a link to a demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2bmVgH9h2Q9uUrp7Q1MfR6/0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appreciate that each `id_product` group of records has one `content` value which is not empty string (or `NULL`?).  We can use a subquery to extract this non empty `content` value for each `id_product` group, and then use a join update query to fill in the empty spaces.

```
UPDATE product p1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id_product, MAX(content) AS content
    FROM products
    GROUP BY id_product
) p2
    ON p1.id_product = p2.id_product
SET p1.content = p2.content
```

Using a `MAX` trick here works, because any letter is greater than empty string, and also `MAX` ignores `NULL` values, so we are covered in either case.

Note that I don't have a `WHERE` clause, because each `id_product` group ends up with all the same `content` values.

Comment: Thanks, as you pointed out not all of the fields were null (my bad) - so I included a `WHERE` clause to ensure `id_code` was 1 instead of the `MAX` check.

Answer (score 2):

Given the structure of your data, this should work:

```
update t join
       t t2
       on t2.id_product = t.id_product and t2.id_code = 1
    set t.content = t2.content
    where t.id_code > 1;
```

Tim's answer is the more general answer.  This answer should be the better performing, if you have an index on `t(id_product, id_code)` or better yet `t(id_product, id_code, content)`.  Or, if your intention is always to use the value from `id_code = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `SELF JOIN` with alias, try the following query:

```
UPDATE products p 
JOIN 
(SELECT a.content, a.id_product FROM 
    (SELECT content, id_product, id_code FROM products) a) b
ON p.id_product = b.id_product AND b.content <> ''
SET p.content = b.content;
```